# API Calls sky-rocketed in Mobile Services

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

My API Calls in Mobile Services suddenly sky-rocketed from 10/7 to 10/9.

How do I know what's causing the problem?

I'm not able to extract useful information from LOG tab in my Mobile Services.

[image]

thanks

Comment: I recommend turning on the other graphs, such as Data Out, HTTP Server errors, etc, which could tell you more. You could enable NewRelic to learn more about what's going on, but somehow you do have a lot of traffic going to your site.

Comment: Everything else seems normal.
What constitutes an api call?
I believe one Rest API call = 1 API Call
What If i have implemented a websocket connection in Mobile Services? With every incoming call via websocket, does it also count as 1 API call?

Comment: Yes, each websocket initiation is one API call.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no HTTP errors coming out of it, then they are hitting your end points. Add some logging to each of your methods and see if they are being invoked. Mobile Services expose a `request` object for Tables and APIs that can tell you a bit about who is calling you.